# I want to validate timezone at the backend which is coming from the frontend in golang

Tags: validation, go, timezone

The front-end is sending timezones along with other user details during sign up. I need to put a validator on timezone for api testing.
The data in the timezone is of the format:

```
(GMT-10:00) Hawaii
(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)
```

What I did is define all the timezones in an array and then search for the received timezone. If it exists then ok else return err. My function is:

```
func timeZoneValidator(field validator.FieldLevel) bool {
    if field.Field().Kind() != reflect.String {
        return false
    }
    timeZoneField := field.Field().String()

    for i:= range timeZones {
        if timeZones[i] == timeZoneField {
            // Found!
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

But I want to use a library or something that does this task for me. If you got any, please advise.

Comment: If you have control over the frontend, see if you can change it so that it sends standard location strings, e.g. "Europe/Berlin". "GMT+01:00 CET" is wrong half the year for people living in Germany, for instance, thanks to DST.

Answer (score 6):

You might be able to use [`time.LoadLocation`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation).

```
func LoadLocation(name string) (*Location, error)
```

You can pass in a string such as "America/New_York" and the error return should tell you if it's valid.

Note the format will be different from what you currently have. Check out https://www.iana.org/time-zones

Comment: time.LoadLocation() can fail with `The system cannot find the path specified` on Windows (golang v1.12.1-v1.12.6).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there is a library for this, but you can optimize the code by using a map insist of the array, so u don't have to iterate over it.

```
_, ok := timeZones[timeZoneField]
return ok
```